# Azure OAuth2: can't validate access token

Tags: java, spring, azure, oauth-2.0, nimbus

I am trying to validate the access token provided by Azure OAuth2. I am using nimbus to validate the token, however I keep getting the "invalid signature" error.

I read on some pages that if the access token contains a nonce, then I won't be able to validate it since it's meant to be used internally by Microsoft only.
I followed the instructions on this page (https://authguidance.com/azure-ad-troubleshooting/) to get the acecss token without a nonce, but it doesn't work.

I can see that the ID token doesn't contain a nonce, but the access token does.

Does anyone know how I can get an access token (withouth a nonce) that I can validate using nimbus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note that, if you validate access token generated with **Microsoft
> Graph** APIs as scope, you will get "Invalid Signature" error as it
> has **`nonce`** claim

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I registered one Azure AD application and added **Microsoft** Graph `API permissions` as below:

[image]

Now I generated **access token** and **id token** using authorization code flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id:<appID>
grant_type:authorization_code
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read openid
code:code
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
client_secret: <secret>
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I decoded the above access token in [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) website, I too got **Invalid Signature** error as it has **`nonce`** claim like below:

[image]
[image]

To get access token without nonce claim, change **`scope`** value to **custom API** instead of Microsoft APIs.

I added Application ID URI and new scope named **`Custom.Read`** by selecting **Expose an API** in my application like this:

[image]

You can find above scope in **My APIs** of your application with same name like this:

[image]

Now, add that scope in **API permissions** of your application like this:

[image]

Make sure to grant **admin consent** to the added permission like below:

[image]

To get **code**, I ran below authorization request in browser like this:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?client_id= <appID>
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri= https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=api://<appID>/.default
&state=12345
```

**Response:**

[image]

Now, I generated access token by changing scope to **custom API** using authorization code flow via Postman like below:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id:<appID>
grant_type:authorization_code
scope: api://<appID>/Custom.Read openid
code:code
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
client_secret: <secret>
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I decoded the above access token in [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) website, it does not have **`nonce`** claim and signature **verified** successfully like below:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I did the same, and I added the scope in my yaml file where I configure azure oauth2 , but I still get the access token with a nonce.

Comment: What you got in in `scp` claim after changing scope?

Comment: I don't get the custom scope in `scp`, I only see the GraphAPI ones there

Comment: Can't figure out why

Comment: Could you try removing Microsoft Graph API scopes and include only custom scope like this `api://<appID>/.default`?

Comment: Is `.default` where my custom scope should go?

Comment: You can try both. For now, try giving the same `api://<appID>/.default`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252079/discussion-between-sridevi-and-turik-mirash).

Comment: It worked after I specified the custom scope under `cloud.azure.active-directory.authorization-clients.graph.scopes`