# OAuth Access Token Exchange Protocol

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, access-token, azure-oauth, token-exchange

We have an application registration on Azure AD to which users authenticate to by requesting their own access token:

```
{
  "aud": "CLIENT_ID",
  "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_ID/v2.0",
  "iat": 1701270410,
  "nbf": 1701270410,
  "exp": 1701274744,
  "aio": "AUQAu/8VAAAAHAdHfHVno15JVZNMHln+AtJiQ5c9jjw5ny4AfK+0gq8siK+6H8bxHnE40bQMa5+oH/oTRxuuy2F/mYdD8w7RyQ==",
  "azp": "04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46",
  "azpacr": "0",
  "name": "USER_FULL_NAME",
  "oid": "USER_OBJECT_ID",
  "preferred_username": "USER_EMAIL_ADDRESS",
  "rh": "0.ARcA9s6n4x-uDUih6CznvYX1DqJqF4JIEcZBhyJIsPIi-CwXAO0.",
  "roles": [
    "READ"
  ],
  "scp": "read",
  "sub": "SVfA-IJg9t-Z73Le-dad5EAOyq3QjwU1oS5csbOTbGI",
  "tid": "TENANT_ID",
  "uti": "vOTt0phu40yVrNAqqj8oAA",
  "ver": "2.0"
}
```

Using this token, the app reg is able to authenticate and authorize the user to execute some code/logic associated to it.

Now we want to use `OAUTH Token Exchange Protocol` so that our app registration can use the user's access token to request a new access token from Snowflake. I know that this is feasible with Oauth  access tokens according to the following article:

https://www.scottbrady91.com/oauth/delegation-patterns-for-oauth-20

so basically one would do something similar to:

```
POST /token
Host: auth.example.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:token-exchange
&client_id=OUR_APP_REG_CLIENT_ID
&client_secret=OUR_APP_REG_CLIENT_SECRET
&scope=api2
&subject_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN
&subject_token_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:access_token
```

but I am not sure if it is possible to achieve it with Snowflake. And if the token exchange protocol can be used with Snowflake; can somebody show us the steps to configure it and what are the other parameters that we have to provide during the `POST` request? Thanks.

Using `On Behalf Of` documentation, I was able to achieve what looks like token exchange using this query:

```
curl.exe -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 

"grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&client_id=

{CLIENT_ID}&client_secret={CLIENT_SECRET}&assertion=

{user_access_token}&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default&requested_tok
en_use=on_behalf_of" 

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

but when validating the token on jwt.io it says that the signature is invalid.

Comment: So that woul be the on behalf flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow

Comment: thanks @Thomas, it looks exactly what we are looking for. but now using this method of on behalf of: I am receiving an Invalid access token signature... ? I posted the curl query in the question body

Comment: is it the user token that is invalid ?

Comment: @AnissChohra You will get "Invalid Signature" error as you are validating the access token generated with **Microsoft Graph** scope. Refer this thread that I previously answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75535497/azure-oauth2-cant-validate-access-token/75541678#75541678

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note that, you will get **"Invalid signature"** error if you trying to validate the access token generated with *Microsoft Graph* scopes.

I registered one Azure AD application and added **permissions** of 2 exposed APIs along with Microsoft Graph API:

[image]

Now, I generated one **user access token** that have similar token claims as you like this:

[image]

When I ran your **curl request** in Postman with Microsoft Graph scope, I got **access token** in response:

```bash
curl.exe -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 

"grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
&client_id={CLIENT_ID}
&client_secret={CLIENT_SECRET}
&assertion={user_access_token}
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&requested_token_use=on_behalf_of" 

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

**Response:**

[image]

> There is no need to **validate** tokens generated with Microsoft Graph API scopes. If you validate it, it will throw *"Invalid Signature"* error.

You can directly call **Microsoft Graph API** using above access token without any validation:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

**Response:**

[image]

> Alternatively, you can generate the token for **other APIs** that are meant for application.

In my case, I ran below **curl request** by replacing **`scope`** with other exposed API value like this:

```bash
curl.exe -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 

"grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
&client_id={CLIENT_ID}
&client_secret={CLIENT_SECRET}
&assertion={user_access_token}
&scope= api://<API_appId>/test.read
&requested_token_use=on_behalf_of" 

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I decoded this token in [jwt.io](https://jwt.io), signature **validated** successfully as below:

[image]
[image]