Nest JS Azure AD Authentication Guard not working
i stumbled in a problem when creating authentication guard in Nestjs to protect my endpoint,
here is my authguard.ts
import {
  CanActivate,
  ExecutionContext,
  Injectable,
  UnauthorizedException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import axios from 'axios';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  private publicKeys: Record<string, string> = {};

  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {}

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const authHeader = request.headers['authorization'];

    if (!authHeader || !authHeader.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException(
        'Authorization header missing or invalid',
      );
    }

    const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];

    // Validate the token
    try {
      const decodedToken = await this.validateToken(token);

      // Attach user details to the request
      request.user = decodedToken;
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid or expired token');
    }
  }

  private async validateToken(token: string): Promise<any> {
    const tenantId = this.configService.get<string>('AZURE_TENANT_ID');
    const clientId = this.configService.get<string>('AZURE_CLIENT_ID');
    const issuer = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/v2.0`;

    if (!tenantId || !clientId) {
      throw new Error('AZURE_TENANT_ID or AZURE_CLIENT_ID is not defined');
    }

    // Decode the token without verifying to extract header
    const decoded = jwt.decode(token, { complete: true }) as {
      header: { kid: string };
    };

    if (!decoded || !decoded.header || !decoded.header.kid) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid token structure');
    }

    const kid = decoded.header.kid;

    // Fetch public keys if not already cached
    if (!this.publicKeys[kid]) {
      const jwks = await this.fetchJwks(issuer);
      this.publicKeys = jwks;
    }

    const publicKey = this.publicKeys[kid];
    if (!publicKey) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException('Public key not found');
    }

    // Verify the token
    return jwt.verify(token, publicKey, {
      issuer,
      audience: clientId,
    });
  }

  private async fetchJwks(issuer: string): Promise<Record<string, string>> {
    const response = await axios.get(`${issuer}/discovery/v2.0/keys`);
    const jwks = response.data.keys;

    const publicKeys: Record<string, string> = {};
    for (const key of jwks) {
      const keyPem = this.convertJwkToPem(key);
      publicKeys[key.kid] = keyPem;
    }

    return publicKeys;
  }

  private convertJwkToPem(jwk: any): string {
    const modulus = Buffer.from(jwk.n, 'base64').toString('base64');
    const exponent = Buffer.from(jwk.e, 'base64').toString('base64');
    return `-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
${modulus}
${exponent}
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----`;
  }
}

here is my controller user.controller.ts to get user profile:
import {
  Controller,
  Get,
  InternalServerErrorException,
  Req,
  Res,
  UseGuards,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { AuthGuard } from 'src/auth/auth.guard';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller('user')
export class UserController {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  @Get()
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard)
  async getUserProfile(
    @Req() req: Request,
    @Res() res: Response,
  ): Promise<any> {
    try {
      const response = await this.userService.getUserProfile(
        req.session.token!,
      );
      res.status(HttpStatus.OK).send(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      const errMessage = 'Error getting user profile: ' + error.message;
      throw new InternalServerErrorException(errMessage);
    }
  }
}

when i call API for login process, it is succesfuly returning me an access token, but when i use that access token as authorization header, it always says 401 Unauthorized: User not logged in, redirecting to login.
here is the response after login:
Token Response: {
  authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<some string>/',
  uniqueId: '<some string>',
  tenantId: '<some string>',
  scopes: [ 'openid', 'profile', 'User.Read', 'email' ],
  account: {
    homeAccountId: '<some string>',
    environment: 'login.windows.net',
    tenantId: '<some string>',
    username: '<some string>',
    localAccountId: '<some string>',
    name: '<some string>',
    nativeAccountId: undefined,
    authorityType: 'MSSTS',
    tenantProfiles: Map(1) { '<some string>' => [Object] },
    idTokenClaims: {
      aud: '<some string>',
      iss: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<some string>/v2.0',
      iat: 1731659325,
      nbf: 1731659325,
      exp: 1731663225,
      auth_time: 1731656361,
      email: '<some string>',
      family_name: '<some string>',
      given_name: '<some string>',
      groups: [Array],
      name: '<some string>',
      oid: '<some string>',
      preferred_username: '<some string>',
      rh: '<some string>',
      roles: [Array],
      sid: '<some string>',
      sub: '<some string>',
      tid: '<some string>',
      uti: '<some string>',
      ver: '2.0',
      wids: [Array]
    },
    idToken: '<some string>'
  },
  idToken: '<some string>',
  idTokenClaims: {
    aud: '<some string>',
    iss: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<some string>/v2.0',
    iat: 1731659325,
    nbf: 1731659325,
    exp: 1731663225,
    auth_time: 1731656361,
    email: '<some string>',
    family_name: '<some string>',
    given_name: '<some string>',
    groups: [
      '<some string>',],
    name: '<some string>',
    oid: '<some string>',
    preferred_username: '<some string>',
    rh: '<some string>',
    roles: [ 'data.read' ],
    sid: '<some string>',
    sub: '<some string>',
    tid: '<some string>',
    uti: '<some string>',
    ver: '2.0',
    wids: [
      '<some string>'
    ]
  },
  accessToken: '<some string>',
  fromCache: false,
  expiresOn: 2024-11-15T09:56:24.000Z,
  extExpiresOn: 2024-11-15T11:19:03.000Z,
  refreshOn: undefined,
  correlationId: '<some string>',
  requestId: '<some string>',
  familyId: '',
  tokenType: 'Bearer',
  state: '',
  cloudGraphHostName: '',
  msGraphHost: '',
  code: undefined,
  fromNativeBroker: false
}

any steps that im missing?

Could you include what authentication flow you used to generate access token?

we use confidential client application with authorization code flow

Have you checked whether you are getting response or not when you call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me with generated access token in tools like Postman?

yes, we could get a proper response if we are using the access token to call the MS graph api (like get user logged profile, get all user in directory)

Then on what call you are getting 401 Unauthorised error? Could you specify that code line?

when i test the guard on user controller (user.controller.ts) it always returned 401

Are you validating the access token generated with Microsoft Graph scopes?

yes, only validating the issuer and audience

The error occurs if you are trying to validate token generated with Microsoft Graph audience. You cannot validate MS Graph token, refer this SO thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77573667/oauth-access-token-exchange-protocol/77577371#77577371. You can directly call /me endpoint to get signed-in user details with generated token instead of validating it.

so how can i guard my endpoint? ensuring only authenticated and authorized user can access the API...

Do you have any custom API exposed in your app registration?

nope, i just use standart RBAC in my entra, just confused how to make sure my API endpoint (lets say /addnewcustomer) can be guarded based on user is authenticated and have the right role claims.. any guidance?

The issue occurs as the token with User.Read scope is meant for Microsoft Graph APIs, not your application.
Since the token's audience (aud) claim doesn't match your API's AZURE_CLIENT_ID, validation fails, leading to a "401 Unauthorized" error.
In your case, expose an API and create new custom scope in app registration after setting app ID URI like this:

You can also create App roles in your app registration as below:

Now, assign these App roles to users and groups under Enterprise application like this:

Before generating access token, make sure to grant these API permissions with consent in your app registration:

While generating access token, make sure to pass scope value as "api://appID/access_as_user".
You can now validate this token and call your custom API based on roles and scp claims of signed-in user:


If you want to make calls to Microsoft Graph for fetching user profile, skip validating the token generated with User.Read scope and directly call /me endpoint.

hi @Sridevi thanks for the response, i will try it
meanwhile i have a question, how to refresh the token in stateless mode (microservice)?

Hi @galih Please post a new question with more details on this and share link here
