Spring Auth0 Library With JWK Provider Cannot Verify Token That Obtained From Azure Entra OIDC By React SPA Authorization Code Flow
Note: The values that used in this question are only sample. E.g.: 3d355765-XXX-47cd-9c7a-bf31179f5XXX
Hello everyone, I have a ReactJS application and a Spring backend application. However, Backend Application cannot verify token and it throws "The Token's Signature resulted invalid when verified using the Algorithm: SHA256withRSA" exception.
Could you please help me to find the reason?
Azure Entra Configuration
In Azure Entra, I only configured this "Authentication" configuration for ReactJS application:

ReactJS Configuration
ReactJS application successfully can get access token from Azure OIDC.
react-oidc-context library is used.
Here is ReactJS configuration:


Spring Backend Configuration With Auth0 Library
I use access_token in header with "Bearer" prefix when I send request to backend application. An example: "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiL....". I can handle that access token. The problem is that I cannot verify it with the publicKey that is obtained from JWK URL.
Libraries
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
        <artifactId>jwks-rsa</artifactId>
        <version>0.22.1</version>
    </dependency>

Implementation
DecodedJWT jwt = JWT.decode(token);
JwkProvider provider = new UrlJwkProvider(new URL("https://login.microsoftonline.com/3d355765-XXX-47cd-9c7a-bf31179f5XXX/discovery/v2.0/keys?appid=5b20cc33-a01b-XXX-be31-cd9ff3aa7XXX"));
Jwk jwk = provider.get(jwt.getKeyId());
Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256((RSAPublicKey) jwk.getPublicKey(), null);
algorithm.verify(jwt);

Library creates this public key:
  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  params: null
  modulus: 26737083189757907003055921442770314338988917140860165426744103322405302728616784576359656902377694864963514916366447987755596040063091127319443429395704125552922128507194605677562878395533638591796237899749004909932248262554836300040575758977279732502744063204426839357267389987189285837088487291113549843075686248327277545438158623612248961469127033882959503541559213717818450130719611600764540097268466124320654392000567544359397082999966622432696244505348004947998457969327542701030616111112222267178710534245286750373749139781560960689184289029103448294950355123548539876783713876691492097395497625781588902647221
  public exponent: 65537

Backend application throws this error at algorithm.verify(jwt); step:

I still don't understand what is missing.
Do you think is there some missing configuration in Azure Entra, ReactJS application or Spring Backend application?

Additional Information
When I use jsonwebtoken library insed of auth0 library:
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.11.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
    <version>0.11.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>0.11.5</version>
</dependency>

I implemented backend application like this:
Jwts.parserBuilder()
        .setSigningKeyResolver(new SigningKeyResolverAdapter() {
        @Override
        public Key resolveSigningKey(io.jsonwebtoken.JwsHeader header, Claims claims) {
            String jwksUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/3d355765-XXX-47cd-9c7a-bf31179f5XXX/discovery/v2.0/keys?appid=5b20cc33-a01b-XXX-be31-cd9ff3aa7XXX";
            String kid = header.getKeyId();
            log.info("kid value: {}", kid);
            try {
                String jwksJson = JWKSFetcher.getJWKS(jwksUrl);
                log.info("jwksJson value: {}", jwksJson);
                return PublicKeyExtractor.getPublicKeyFromJWKS(jwksJson, kid);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
          }
      })
       .build()
       .parseClaimsJws(token)
       .getBody();

The jsonwebtoken library throws this exception:

JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity
cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.



AN UPDATE: "ISSUER IS DIFFERENCES" (06.08.2024)
Today, I noticed there is issuer differences. Could it be a cause of the my problem?
I obtained the token from https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{MY_TENANT_ID}}/v2.0
The issuer in the token that comes back is https://sts.windows.net//{{MY_TENANT_ID}}/ which doesn't match.
When I check the config at .well-known/openid-configuration the issuer is as expected https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{MY_TENANT_ID}}//v2.0
And also, JWKS endpoint returns this issuer: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{MY_TENANT_ID}}//v2.0
I updated manifest file:

But, unfortunately I still get token with v1.0:



AN UPDATE: "Cannot Verify Access_Token but Id_Token Works" (09.08.2024)
I know that it shouldn't be and it is strange but, while the backend application cannot verify access_token and getting 'Signature verification failed" exception, in the other hand, it can  verify the id_token.

Can you share your GitHub repo or complete code in the question?

Hello Dasari, I really would love to do that but unfortunately it is being developed in the company private repo. Therefore, I cannot do it.

Hi @DasariKamali, I updated the question. Could you please check this section of the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78926351/spring-auth0-library-with-jwk-provider-cannot-verify-token-that-obtained-from-az#:~:text=AN%20UPDATE%3A%20%22ISSUER%20IS%20DIFFERENCES%22

Your react app is a public OAuth2 client, which is now considered a bad practice. Have a look at this article I wrote, it contains a React app consuming a Spring REST backend using the OAuth2 BFF pattern.

Hello @ch4mp, I know that always a better way can be found. However, in our case, at least for the first step of our business requirement, we want to do it our way. It is the simplest and recommended secure way to handle tokens over SPA with the PCKE method. Improving the backend side is our further plan. In my case, I don't want to discuss best practices. I need to find a way to validate tokens on the backend side. All I need is this right now. Thanks for your comment, by the way.

Hi @Ali, you cannot validate tokens generated with Microsoft Graph scope. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75535497/azure-oauth2-cant-validate-access-token/75541678#75541678. You need to expose an API and add new scope for which you can generate tokens with version 2.0 and validate them.

Could you include what value you are getting in aud claim of decoded access token?

"It is the [...] recommended secure way to handle tokens over SPA with the PCKE" wrong. Read this post from Spring Security team. Just a sample, you can find other articles from serious security experts explaining why both of using public clients (even with PKCE), and exposing tokens to remote frontends are bad ideas.

Hello @Sridevi, yes I haven't configured scope yet and also here is aud information: "aud": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"

Note that, open_id and offline_access are Microsoft Graph scopes which generates token with aud as 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 that gives "Invalid Signature" error when you validate it.
To resolve that, you need to expose API by creating custom scopes and generate token with those custom scopes.
For sample, I exposed an API in an app registration and created custom scopes in it as below:

Make sure to change "requestedAccessTokenVersion" to 2 in App's Manifest for generating access token of version 2.0 :

Now, I added these API permissions and granted consent in application from which token will be generated like this:

Initially, I ran below authorization request in browser and got code value in address bar after successful authentication:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=pkceappId
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=api://customApiAppId/test.read api://customApiAppId/test.write
&state=12345
&code_challenge=xxxxxxxx
&code_challenge_method=S256


Later, I generated access token using authorization code with PKCE flow via Postman like this:
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:authorization_code
client_id:pkceappId
scope: api://customApiAppId/test.read api://customApiAppId/test.write
code:code
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
code_verifier:S256

Response:

When I decoded this token in jwt.io, signature verified successfully and token generated with version 2.0 as below:


In your case, expose an API by creating new custom scope and use those new custom scope values in ssoScopes parameter while generating the access token.
Make sure not to pass Microsoft Graph scopes like openid or offline_access in  ssoScopes parameter.
Reference:
java - Azure OAuth2: can't validate access token - Stack Overflow by me

I have a simmilar issue, I found a blog that solves this problem
. If you decode access_token you will see 2 issues

nonce claim in header token makes it impossible to be validated because by default scope opnenid offline_access will create a valid token only for MSGraph API. You need to create a customized scope for your APIs
iss claim is incorrect because Azure AD supports both tokens v1.0 and v2.0. The access tokens always match the format expected by the Web API regardless of request endpoint v1.0 or v2.0. You can update the format of WebAPI to v2.0 in App registration -> Manifest 

{
   ...    
   “accessTokenAcceptedVersion”: 2
   ...
}

